# Use argparse module in python to parse a single argument

Tags: python, argparse

I used the OptParse module a few years back, and it seemed so easy, but seeing the argparse module, it doesn't seem intuitive to use. Thus, I'd like some help.

I currently have (which isnt much yet):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.parse_args()
```

I'd like to be able to issue a command like `python myscript.py --char 20` . This `value` for `char` flag will always be an `int`.

If someone can please help, I'd greatly appreciate it! Thank you

Comment: Have you considered adding the argument you want to take to the parser? What's the *problem?*

Comment: I think a quick Google search answers this question the best.

Comment: This task isn't significantly different between `optparse` and `argparse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you add an argument, and retrieve it:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('--char', type=int,
                   help='number of characters')

args = parser.parse_args()
char = args.char
```

You should check out the docs:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

And here's a tutorial:
https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html

Comment: There's a section at the end of the `argparse` docs about translating `optparse` to `argparse`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add an argument to the parser object, and optionally specify the parameter `type` to be `int`

```
# testargs.py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--char', type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.char)
```

if you execute this file with

```
python testargs.py --char 20
```

it should print `20` to the console

Comment: Just a point of caution: `type=int` means, `"use the int() function to convert the string to a number"`.  This expression is similar to, but not quite the same as the optparse `parser.add_option("-n", type="int", dest="num")`.